# Why is the generator not working in Shopify Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify-app

I am attempting to build an online store using the Shopify Gem. I have added `gem shopify_api` to the Gemfile and run `bundle install` and also `bundle update`. However when I run the next command:

```
rails generate shopify_app -api_key=[API_KEY_HERE]-secret=[SECRET_KEY_HERE]
```

I get the following error:

```
Could not find generator 'shopify_app'. Maybe you meant 'scaffold', 'scss:assets' or 'controller'
Run `rails generate --help` for more options.
```

I have tried restarting the rails server and it had no effect. Why am I getting this error and how should I proceed?

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'shopify_api'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.6'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development
gem 'simple_form'


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

When I run the command `rails generate --help` I get the following

```
C:\Sites\postgresapp>rails generate --help
Usage: rails generate GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
  -h, [--help]     # Print generator's options and usage
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output

Please choose a generator below.

Rails:
  assets
  channel
  controller
  generator
  helper
  integration_test
  jbuilder
  job
  mailer
  migration
  model
  resource
  scaffold
  scaffold_controller
  task

Coffee:
  coffee:assets

Graphql:
  graphql:enum
  graphql:install
  graphql:interface
  graphql:loader
  graphql:mutation
  graphql:object
  graphql:union

Js:
  js:assets

SimpleForm:
  simple_form:install

TestUnit:
  test_unit:generator
  test_unit:plugin
```

EDIT: I have found a partial answer to my question. from the Gem documentation it states:

> This gem requires Ruby 2.3.1 as of version 4.3. If you need to use an
>   older Ruby version then update your Gemfile to lock onto an older
>   release than 4.3.

Since I am using ruby version 2.2.6 I need to specify an older version of the gem. so I will narrow my question down further to: how can I know which version of the Shopify Gem to use?

Answer (score 0):

`bundle list` will list all of your gems with their versions

`bundle list | grep shopify` will show you details about your Shopify gem

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include `gem 'shopify_app'` into your gemfile and bundle install again. I can see you have the `shopify_api` gem but not the `shopify_app` gem which has the generator.